# In Beamer, how do you change the background color of an enumerated list inside an exampleblock?

Tags: beamer

I am trying to set the background color of the numbers in numbered lists that appear in my example blocks in Beamer. I thought this would do it:

```
\setbeamercolor{item projected example}{fg=red, bg=yellow}
```

It does not work. In the example below, I would like to have the numbers "1" and "2" on a dark green background.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) it's hard to tell, but the following seems to produce what you want

[image]

The important line is

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[square]
```

Note that the colour of the `\item` will change within the `example` block, but not outside of it.

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[square]
\usecolortheme{rose}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Inside an example}
\begin{example}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item hello
    \item world
  \end{enumerate}
\end{example}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outside example}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. It has greatly simplified my template too!

Comment: @gonzalomedina: While the answer by cmhughes shows the cleaner approach, your answer is more generic and just shows a different approach. I don't think it should be deleted.